# Masters in Math degrees without requiring bachelor's in math

Tags: mathematics, masters

I did a Bachelor's in Economics, having taken several modules in statistics and econometrics and 1 in math. Now I'm very keen to do a masters in math or applied math, with the possibility to further studies in research, but am not sure which universities would admit me into their program given that most of their websites state they require a Bachelor's in math.

I am currently contacting various program administrators in different universities in the US, Europe and Singapore, but would very much appreciate help that anyone can give to help me in my search.

Does anybody know of any programs that are willing to admit students without math bachelor's, with the possibility of taking some bridging courses during/prior to the Master's program?

Comment: Most places in the US. The less competitive the easier.

Comment: In the US another term that may be good to look for is a Post-Bac program in Math (though some are more aimed at people looking to do a PhD program after so you'll need to do research on the individual programs)

Comment: @GageMartin I see, thanks for this suggestion. So far I have not come across a Post-Bac program, is this common in the US?

Comment: @FourierFlux Oh I see. I'm considering university of colorado, washington, illinois. Would you consider these competitive, or mid range?

Comment: *(US perspective)* You might want to carefully reread the requirements for some of the universities, as I suspect many include something like "or the equivalent coursework background". I've known plenty of people who got undergraduate degrees in physics, philosophy, and even more remote areas who later went into math (and the other direction also). I seriously doubt it's a math **degree** that's desired, but rather convincing evidence that you have the appropriate background and potential to succeed in the program, and having a **degree** is simply the most common way to show this.

Comment: If you want to study applied mathematics, maybe consider one of the several "industrial mathematics" masters programs, such as [Master of Science in Industrial Mathematics at Michigan State University](https://math.msu.edu/msim/default.aspx) ([admission requirements](https://math.msu.edu/msim/admission_requirements.aspx)). I recall posting a list of several such programs once, but it must have been in a Stack Exchange comment (which google doesn't find) rather than a Stack Exchange answer, but you can probably find several yourself by googling.

Comment: It certainly isn't unusual, you can see a (probably not exhaustive) list of some programs here https://mathalliance.org/our-partners/post-baccalaureate-programs/

Answer (score 3):

This is, typically, very difficult without taking courses in real analysis, numerical analysis, differential equations, and other applied mathematics topics that you won’t get in a traditional economics program.

Your chances would be, frankly, very low without proper preparation from mathematics undergraduate courses. I did an economic major with a math minor, and I am still upgrading a few courses here and there to go into an applied math PhD, but this would be similar to a masters degree because of the pre-requisites.

Take a year or two, get the background, and then you would be much more competitive. Perhaps you can illuminate what math courses, particularly, you’ve taken.

Comment: The question is specifically asking about a Master's level program but your answer seems to be in reference to a PhD program

Comment: Edited slightly. I believe my argument still stands for a masters degree as well. There are just so many pre-requisite courses that, if you did not take as a minor or for ones own education, that you’d be nearly beat out by everybody in the applicant pool with the prerequisites.

Comment: @GrayLiterature Thanks for your frankness. I only took 1 math course that is more like an introduction to calculus with several theorems such as green's theorem, l'hopital's rule, but did not take the courses on linear algebra and real analysis etc. I graduated 2 years ago. Right now I am taking an Udemy course on linear algebra, and asking my home university if I can take several math courses. The annoying thing is the administration and rigidity in the types of courses permitted for alumni to enrol in. What are you doing right now to upgrade your courses?

Comment: @Hazel Lim: You should include your course work and other math-related background in your question. I just wrote a comment that would probably have been different (or not written at all) if I had known that your background was so little. The people I was talking about from other fields had rather strong backgrounds in math --- they simply didn't major in math for some reason (didn't want to take the capstone math course, didn't take a required physics course needed for math but not for philosophy, etc.).

Comment: I would not waste your time and effort with Udemy for mathematics. What you need is a credit on your transcript from an accredited institution. That said, there are online universities (again, need to be careful here) that offer modules for self-learning equivalent to what you get in a course, but you’re very much on your own. If this is something you want to do, you’d be best to speak with an advisor on the optimal path forward based upon geography, needs, etc